# <li> border not including all items in it

Tags: html, css

I'm making navigation tabs and when a tab is active or "current" I want a border to appear at the bottom of that tab, but the border is including the icon only and not the text...

my HTML

```
<li class="current"><a href="#tab-3"><img src="assets/related.svg" 
height="20px" width="20px">Related</a></li>
```

my CSS

```
.tabs-menu li.current {
         position: relative;
         font-weight: bold;
         border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    }
```

this is what I'm getting

[image]

and here's a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/qxL6w0yf/

I need it to look like this 
[image]

Note: in the fiddle the tabs aren't working for some reason, but that's irrelevant, I think. Thanks.

Comment: Well that's because you are limiting the height to 30px ...

Comment: @CBroe That actually fixed it lol... I didn't see that line. Can you add that as an answer so you can get the green tick =) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you are limiting the height for `ul` and `li` to 30px,remove them.**

*Change like :*

```
.tabs-menu li {
    height: 30px;<---------------------Remove Or 50px
    //More codes......
}

.tabs-menu {
      height: 30px;<---------------------Remove Or 50px
      //More codes......
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyo56n7t/1/)

Comment: Could you help me understand what the jQuery is needed for? The issue in question seems to be entirely style based, rather than functionality.

Comment: @ehsan I'm not really sure how that's gonna fix the issue, as it would produce the same thing. Tried it in the fiddle and didn't work. However as @CBroe suggested, it was the `height` that was causing it. It's been solved. Thank you.

Comment: @MarwanAK , i insert  fiddle demo.see it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add an `a` at the end. Otherwise, it's ignoring the nested `a` tag.

```
.tabs-menu li.current a {
```

This produces the results you're looking for when I added it to your code sample.

Comment: That does put the line under the text yes, but the line will only extend as long as the text does, and that looks weird. I need to have the line extending for the full width of the <li> item